# How to auto-complete the HTML tag (lang, utf etc) at the beginning on VS code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find a way to auto-complete the HTML tag at the beginning on VS code?

eg the lang, charset, utf? etc thank you!

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: try this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `!`. Just type `!` into an empty HTML file and hit enter.
You will have a basic HTML structure with meta tags like `lang` and `charset`.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 2021

Auto-closing tags is now part of the HTML language features provided *"out of the box"* by **V.S. Code**. The following configurations allows users to turn the configure the setting so that it is ***ON***, or ***OFF***.

---

##### `"html.autoClosingTags": (true/false)"`

---

The extension that use to be needed for auto-closing tags, still has a purpose though, which is why you will find that people are still adding it to their editor. The **AUTO-TAG** extension bundle (see the photo below) adds linked-tag renaming support. So when you change the the inner element-name of an opening tag, the closing tag auto-fills with the same character sequence (or name) as what the user types in the opening tag. The extension works in reverse to. One can rename a closing tag, while using the extension, and the opening tag that is coupled with the altered closing tag will also take on the new character sequence as what was entered into the closing tag.

---

[image]

---